# Storing temporary files Java

Tags: java, download, temporary

I was wondering what is the best way to temporarily have a file on your PC?

I have a program where you can view PDFs from a website. To view these PDFs you need to have them locally on your PC and then open them. Now I was wondering where would be the best place to save these PDFs (these PDFs should only be saved temporarily and not remain on the computer).

Is there any normal procedure for something like that, like temporary files are always stored in a certain folder, or is there any way to download the PDFs compressed?

I would be glad about any suggestion on this topic.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)

Comment: One  can add a system hook, so files are deleted on application exit. The link has also support for temporary _directories_. PDFs might be compressed additionally, but then `Desktop.getDesktop().open(...)` will not work.

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks for the input. Does createTempFile from your posted doucmentation, also deletes the file on application exit? Or do I have to specific delete the pdf on application exit?

Comment: There is `File.deleteOnExit` for that; it is mentioned in the javadocs in the following method below.